Understanding the rolling motion of a circle on $\mathbb{R}$ in terms of parallel transport and Ehresmann connections
I am trying to understand a toy example to help build my intuition about connections on fiber bundles and parallel transport. My main issue is trying to understand if and how the "no-slip" rolling motion of a circle can be viewed "naturally" from the point of view of (Ehresmann) connections.
Consider the system of a unit circle $S^1$ rolling on the real line $\mathbb{R}$.
The configuration of the system can be thought of as a point in an $S^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{R}$ denoted by $\pi: E \to \mathbb{R}$. It seems natural to choose the trivial bundle $\mathbb{R} \times S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$, because we have globally defined coordinates $x$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\theta$ on $S^1$ . So will assume that $E = \mathbb{R} \times S^1$ (but maybe there is a better choice?). The configuration of the system is then a point in $\mathbb{R} \times S^1$, which can be globally parametrized by the coordinates $(x, \theta)$ of the point of contact in each space.
By constraining the motion of the circle with a "no-slip" condition, we can define an Ehresmann connection, which amounts to a choice of horizontal subspace $H_{(x, \theta)}$ of $T_{(x, \theta)}(\mathbb{R} \times S^1)$ at each point $(x, \theta)$, as follows
$$H_{(x, \theta)} = \text{span}\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg\vert_{(x, \theta)} - \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\bigg\vert_{(x, \theta)}\right\}$$
where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg\vert_{(x, \theta)}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\bigg\vert_{(x, \theta)}$ correspond to $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\bigg\vert_x, 0\right)$ and $\left(0, \frac{d}{d\theta}\bigg\vert_\theta\right)$ in the identification $T_{(x, \theta)}(\mathbb{R} \times S^1) \cong T_x\mathbb{R} \times T_\theta S^1$, respectively.
Parallel motion under this connection ensures that the angular velocity of the circle be always such that the point of contact has zero linear velocity at all times, which is the "no-slip" condition.
It seems to me that the "no-slip" condition should be natural in some sense, but I don't really see how the connection that I have defined is natural.
There is one choice of Ehresmann connection that looks more natural than all others, and that is the one where the horizontal space is $H_{(x, \theta)} = \text{span}\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg\vert_{(x, \theta)}\right\}$. If we endow $\mathbb{R} \times S^1$ with the product metric (of the Euclidean and round metrics) then the natural choice of horizontal subspace is the orthogonal complement of the vertical spaces. However, the parallel transport induced by this connection is the one where the circle is simply translated along $\mathbb{R}$ with no rotation (the point of contact remains the same as the circle moves around).
This parallel transport also seems "natural" so it is not surprising that it would arise from a "natural" choice of connection. But the parallel transport arising from "no-slip" rolling motion also seems "natural" but I don't see in what sense the connection I have defined above is "natural". There are infinitely many connections one could define where the subspace is spanned by a vector $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + a\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$ for some $a \neq 0$. I can't see a condition in terms of the metrics that would make this particular choice $a = -1$ natural.
So my question is, can the "no-slip" rolling motion be understood in a "natural" way in terms of connections and parallel transport, and if so, how? I am using "natural" in quotes because I don't have a precise sense of how to define it, but I am hoping that there is such a way.

It seems to me that no slipping corresponds to $a=-1$. What am I missing?

@TedShifrin I used an angle coordinate in radians. In terms of the arclength parametrization it would be $-1$ yes. But even with $a = -1$, I am not sure why it is natural. In fact that already illustrates the problem, it's sensitive to the coordinate choice on $S^1$...

We all use angles measured in radians. Not slipping means that the horizontal translation is equal to the arclength rolled along the circle; since the radius is $1$, this means that $x=-\theta$, no? Why should a local coordinates formula not depend on the choice of local coordinates? You haven't written an intrinsic formula.

@TedShifrin ah you are absolutely right I don't know what I was thinking. The arclength is already equal to $\theta$... Sorry about that. I will correct this. But I guess I don't know how to express this condition in an intrinsic way.

Hm perhaps what I need is to say that at the point of contact $(x(t), \theta(t))$, the tangent spaces $T_{x(t)}\mathbb{R}$ and $T_{\theta(t)}S^1$ are linearly isometric (in a canonical way given the Euclidean and round metrics, via the map $\varphi: \frac{d}{dx}\bigg\vert_{x(t)} \to \frac{d}{d\theta}\bigg\vert_{\theta(t)}$), and no-slip means that $v = (x'(t), \theta'(t))$ satisfies $\varphi(d\pi_1(v)) = d\pi_2(v)$ in terms of the projections onto $\mathbb{R}$ and $S^1$.
